# Node.js hiding contents of HTML page until user has logged in

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, bootstrap-modal

I currently have a basic HTML page (the main feature being a form) with contents being loaded and changed via node.js server-side code.

I have created a login modal and I have a .json file that contains details about each user including their username and password.

Currently, I am not doing any sort of verification (I am not interested in security at the moment). The problem is, I am unsure how to hide the content of the HTML page from users that are not logged in.

I was thinking about using HTML `<template>` tags around the HTML content but I am unsure whether or not they can be accessed via node.js.

Does anyone have any other suggestions that could possibly help as I am quite new to node.js and Javascript in general?

*This is the format that my .json file takes:*

```
[
   {"name":"preset1","password":"pass1",...},
   {"name":"preset2","password":"pass2",...}
]
```

*This is the server-side code that is activated when the modal login form is submitted:*

```
app.post("/login", function(req, res) {
  var username = req.body.username;
  var password = req.body.password;
  fs.readFile("results.json", function(err, data) {
    var json = JSON.parse(data);

    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
      if (json[i]["name"] === username && json[i]["password"] === password) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    console.log("inavlid");
  });
});
```

Comment: So does your express server generate the HTML? Or do you just have static HTML files which does the login request via Javascript?

Comment: I have a  .ejs file with all the HTML content which is updated when post requests are made to the server. For the modal, when the submit button is clicked, it's just the server that responds.

Comment: Search for protected routes, you use a middleware function isLogged or something. Also, you can pass variables to your ejs to do condicional rendering